# foreignobject is not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, svg, html5-canvas

I want to draw HTML text in canvas using foreignobject element, In MDN i can see the below link (see reference), this is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla browser but not in IE10, I am using IE10.

Browser Mode: IE10 & Document Mode: Standards

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Error:

```
DOM7000: Access Denied. Resource access is restricted for cross-origin URL: 'blob:7C72C95F-3E3F-4CD6-804C-C2D8CCC06283'.
```

file:

Below is the code snippet : -

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
            <p><canvas id="canvas" style="border:2px solid black;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
            <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
                         "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                           "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:40px'>" +
                             "<em>I</em> like <span style='color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;'>cheese</span>" +
                           "</div>" +
                         "</foreignObject>" +
                       "</svg>";
            var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
            var img = new Image();
            var svg = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
            img.src = url;
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 12):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28SVG%29) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh834675%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), IE11 and below do not support `<foreignObject>`.

Comment: thanks, if there is a way by which we can implement the same in IE10 ?

Comment: This is unfortunate, foreignObject is a terrific way obtain SVG support for E-Z text handling as html in <div>s and so forth.  In declarative mode versus fiddling with text via JavaScript.

Comment: I made some test on foreignobject and it seams to work in my IE9. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14316104/foreignobject/pages/page0001-ie-plain.html Why is my example working? Is there a minimal support by IE9?

Comment: Because in html unknown tags contents may be rendered as text.

Answer (score 2):

Html2canvas (beta) seems to work in Explorer 10 (at least in my virtualbox)
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

example: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try Chromeframe, but it looks like they're retiring it next year :(

https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/