# Drawing DOM elements (SVGs as foreign elements) on a canvas doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, svg, draw

I have successfully used [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) technique, to **draw user input from DOM elements (such as input and selection fields) on a canvas and make it available as an image.**

This works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but **on Internet Explorer 11 , I get the following error**:

- ***XML5634: An attribute with the same name already exists on this element. Line: 1, Column 242*** , when I try on the full site I 've
  developed. This error is supposedly shown when there are duplicate values on name and id fields but I checked every element on the DOM and there is none.
- ***Unexpected call to method or property access.*** , when I try to reproduce the whole procedure on this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/5mf4n7v3/  . It seems from the debugger that the error  happens when   `ctx.drawImage()` is called.

Essentially, what I am trying to do in this fiddle is to **draw the SVG yellow circle image and an arbitrary SVG, provided by me, on the canvas**. This seems to work in all major browsers except IE11. Is there anyone else having faced the same problem and knows some workaround?

Comment: IE does not support the `<foreignObject>` tag.

Comment: So there is no workaround for that ?

Comment: Not unless you count Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera as workarounds.

Comment: Bump. Same issue here using canvg to export some SVGs and PNGs from IE11. Works in other browsers.

Comment: Anyone found any solution?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739672/foreignobject-is-not-working-in-ie10

Answer (score 1):

IE 10 did not support `<foreignObject>` tag, but you did not need it to draw text on canvas, here i rewrite you fiddle, so now it works in IE - http://jsfiddle.net/skyr9999/5hhpo76h